# Subset data based on string values

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to subset my data frame based on the `index` column; I would like to keep those cases whose index is saved in `myvar` (eg. 110, 111). I don't understand why I receive 0 observations when running this code:

```
newdata <- df[ which(df$index=="myvars"), ]
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(index = c(111, 110, 101, 111), et = c(1, 1, 1, 
1), d1_t2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), d1_t3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), d1_t4 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1), d2_t1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), d2_t2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), d2_t3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1), d2_t4 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), d3_t1 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), d3_t2 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1), d3_t3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), d3_t4 = c(1, 1, 0, 1), d4_t1 = c(0, 
0, 1, 1), d4_t2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1), d4_t3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), d4_t4 = c(1, 
0, 1, 1), d5_t1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1), d5_t2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), d5_t3 = c(1, 
0, 1, 1), d5_t4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), d6_t1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1), d6_t2 = c(0, 
0, 1, 1), d6_t3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), d6_t4 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), d7_t1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1), d7_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), d7_t3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), d7_t4 = c(1, 
0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
myvars<-c("110", "111")
```

Comment: In your example you search for the string "myvars", which is not in your data.frame. You have to use your vector `myvars`. And btw, if your df entries are numeric, myvars entries also have to be numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
myvars<-c(110, 111)  # <-- !! no quotes !!
df[ which(df$index %in% myvars ), ] #also, no quotes round myvars
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several basic problems with what you are trying to do.

1. You are not using the variable 'myvars' -- you are using a string with the value "myvars". None of your rows has the index "myvars".
2. You are using `==` which is good for one value (e.g. `values==4`), but myvars has multiple values in it. Instead, you could use `df$index %in% myvars`
3. This does work, but you have integer indices, and are accessing them with strings. This is unnecessary, and could lead to problems in other places.
4. You may be confused because of your very large and complex example data. You only need one column to test -- not twenty.